# Use Nifi to copy/move logs from different Nifi servers into AWS S3

Tags: apache-nifi

We have a Nifi cluster of 4 servers and we want to ingest the logs of all the servers on S3 . Is there a way in Nifi using which we can ingest the logs of each Nifi server to S3. Logs on each node are stored on its local (separate disk mounted for Nifi logs -: /data/logs/nifi)

Comment: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-aws-nar/1.15.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.aws.s3.PutS3Object/index.html

Comment: or you could find implementations of logger rolling strategy that uploads old logs to S3: https://github.com/link-nv/logback-s3-rolling-policy